# Antd table column width issue

Tags: width, antd, ellipsis, column-width, ant-design-pro

I use antd table in my project and often use a horizontal scroll when there are many columns in a table that cannot be displayed in a single frame. The **width** for each column is defined. It was working fine in previous days but now i am having a problem with column width. **The column width is not working properly if i don't apply ellipsis to each column**. Is there any way to fix it rather than using ellipsis separately for each column?

```
    const tableColumns = () => { 
return [
        {
          title: 'col one',
          dataIndex: 'throws',
          key: 'throws',
          width:110,
          ellipsis: true,
          sorter: (a, b) => stringValueSort(a.throws, b.throws),
        },
        {
          title: 'col two',
          dataIndex: 'bats',
          key: 'bats',
          width:90,
          ellipsis: true,
          sorter: (a, b) => stringValueSort(a.bats, b.bats),
        },
      ] 
    };
```

If i use **ellipsis: true** property columns width automatically adjust according to the text content in column. Width of the column still not been applied using this **width** property.

Comment: share your code please

Comment: code is added for the above question now

Comment: Your problem is all about scroll, then set both height and width. then check the result

Comment: yes fixed. Previously i was using scroll as Boolean but now i have given scroll width in pixels and issue is fixed for the columns width. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if antd table width 100% not working:

```css
.ant-table-fixed {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.ant-table-tbody > tr > td {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.antd-table-custom-class thead th, .antd-table-custom-class tbody td {
 white-space:pre-wrap;
 text-overflow: ellipsis
}
```

**if you want to see whole text please**

```
.antd-table-custom-class thead th, .antd-table-custom-class tbody 
 td
 {    white-space: nowrap;
      word-break:break-word;
      word-break: break-all
 }
```

Comment: .antd-table-custom-class thead th, .antd-table-custom-class tbody td {
   white-space: nowrap;
   word-break:break-word;
   word-break: break-all
}